# ExactTarget: API and Arrays

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

I am working on setting up an API triggered email for a purchase confirmation email. Since one customer can purchase more than one product the API will send the product, image, and price through an array.

My question is how would I go about displaying this information properly formatted in the email that the customer will receive?

I looked at the documentation in ET, but it has been confusing identifying the correct example to use. It seems that their documentation when working with API focuses more on the API and not on the AMPScript.

I would appreciate any suggestions or if you could point me in the right direction within the ET documentation.

Thank you!
Gaudy

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend sending over the line-item details in a single attribute, formatted in XML, using CDATA where appropriate.  In the email scripting you can create a rowset from the XML using the [BuildRowSetFromXML()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromXML) function and then iterate through each line-item, outputting the results.

Utilizing XSLT is also an option with the [TransformXML()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TransformXML) function.